# Array of undefined UDT

Tags: vb6

In VB6 I am trying to create an array of an undefined UDT. I explain myself.
Let's imagine I have 3 UDT:

```
Public Type Country
  Countryproperty1 as String
  Countryproperty2 as Date
End type

Public type City
  Cityproperty1 as String
  Cityproperty2 as Date
End type

Public type Street
  Streetproperty as string 
  Streetproperty as date
End type
```

How can I declare an array which can welcome any of these types ?

Thanks a lot !
Pierrick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to put UDTs into an array of type `Variant`, but only if the UDTs are defined in a public class module.

Public class modules can only be defined in one of the ActiveX project types. So first, if your project is of type "Standard EXE", change it to "ActiveX EXE" from the project properties dialog, and change the start mode to "Standalone" rather than "ActiveX Component". (Or, add an ActiveX DLL/Control project and reference it from the main project.)

Then add a Class Module to the project, and set its "Instancing" property to anything other than "1 - Private". Move your UDT definitions into this class module.

Now you'll be able to put your UDTs in any array of type `Variant`.

An alternative approach is to do your types as class modules rather than UDTs. This doesn't require an ActiveX project type so it is also usable from VBA or from the Learning Edition of VB6. In this case you will have 3 class modules, one for each UDT. Remove the `Public Type ...` and `End Type` and put the fields of the types as `Public` fields of the class modules. Since these will be `Object`s, they have very different handling to UDTs. They'll use `Set` for assignment, and `New` to create instances (e.g., `Set c1 = New Country`). Assignment will assign the objects without cloning them. The array type in this case will be `Object`.